# Create arraylist from list of maps for certain key value with java 8

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream

I have an object with a list of maps. Each map looks like this:

```
{
  id: "something",
  link: "someLink"
}
```

I am trying to create an array list of all the id's in the maps. I can do this with a simple loop

```
 List<String> Ids = new ArrayList<>();
        
 List<Map<String, String>> maps = pojo.getMaps();
        
 for(Map<String, String> map: maps) {
       Ids.add(map.get("id"));
    }
```

But how is this done in one line using java 8 streams? I have never used it with maps so I am lost.
I assume it would be along the lines of something like this but i honestly dont know

```
List<String> ids = pojo.getMaps().stream().map(Map.Entry::  ???? ).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: This should do the trick: `.map(m -> m.get("id")).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `pojo.getMaps().stream()`

So far, so good. You now have a stream of `Map<String, String>` objects. We need to just get the keys from this. So, given one of your weird map things, how do we turn that into the key value?

Looks like a trivial `map.get("id")` does that job, no?

So let's put that in the lambda:

`pojo.getMaps().stream().map(theMap -> theMap.get("id"))`

and now we have a `Stream<String>` with ids.

### HOWEVER, big note!

The fact that you start out with a map object that looks like an object is a giant code smell. Most likely you should go back a few steps in your project and fix that instead. You really ought to have a class that represents this link concept:

```
@Value
public class Link {
    String id, link;
}
```

and go from there:

```
listOfLinks.stream().map(Link::getId).distinct().collect(...);
```

NB: The above uses [Lombok's `@Value`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Value).

### functional is just a tool

Note that there is no need to rewrite your code to 'use java 8 features'. Compare:

```
    var ids = pojo.getMaps().stream()
      .map(m -> m.get("id"))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

with:

```
    var ids = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (var m : pojo.getMaps()) ids.add(m.get("id"));
```

it's about the same amount of code.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and advice

Answer (score 1):

You can use get the value of `id` from map same way in loop. Here `.map()` used to transform `Map<String, String>` to `String` means transform Map to value of key `id`

```
List<String> ids = pojo.getMaps().stream()                 // Stream<Map<String, String>>
                                 .map(e -> e.get("id"))    // Stream<String> 
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```